# How to go to the fragment from different activity and that fragment which is the part of navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdYSj.jpg)Someone help me to solve this issue, struggling with activities and fragments but not able to understand it properly.
I've a navigation drawer with

> multiple fragments

and moving to

> new activity

from one of the fragment and have few more activities, at the last I want to come back to one of the fragment from navigation drawer from the activity, How can I do this?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: if you'r struggling with fragments and activities scenario implement `BaseActivity` which will be `abstract` class and extends your all activities with that base activity in which your navigation drawer code will be there.

Comment: If you calling from activity from fragment and want to back to that fragment then just simply call `finish()` method.

Comment: Please describe the problem more specifically. Describe a specific user interaction with your app.

Comment: i dont want to go to the same fragment, I want to display the final result in different fragment of navigation drawer

Comment: `Fragment` will be called from activity. And if you want to call fragment from fragment then you need to use `getChildFragmentManager()`.

Comment: ya, I have a navigation drawer with multiple fragments, I wanted to show navigation drawer for all activities which I tried but I  could not do it, that is the reason now from the fragment of navigation I am coming to new activity and doing all the tasks in activities but the final book details which the user purchased he should be able to see that in any of the fragment in first activity itself, How can i directly access the fragment from my final activity?

Comment: Its a really unclear thing for me what are you trying to say ? Its better to share some hand drawing

Comment: You should edit your question instead of posting comments. Please make all code snippets as complete as possible. In particular put code inside a method inside a class just like you really do in Java.

Comment: If you want to last fragment then you should clear all previous fragments from the stacks.

Comment: It is my navigation drawer, every fragment has different data and user should be able to see result in respective fragments, if i clear what about all other fragments ?

Comment: Can anyone say how to perform it, I have a fragment in the activity, and in that fragment I have a button , onclick of that button starting new fragment, now if I click back press activity is closing other than coming back to old fragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may go from frangment to activity by using intent like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), YOURACTIVITY.class);
                startActivity(i)
```

And if you want to return from activity to fragment then you may use finish() method on Click of BackPressed in Activity .So, when you press back button then your current activity will be finish and your last showing fragment will available to show. For backpres you may use these lines of code.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        finish();
    }
```

Comment: I have 7 fragments in navigation drawer, I want to show the final output into 5th fragment  from my different activity which is not the navigation activity.

Comment: Let me more clear. Activity A which is navigation with few fragments. I am coming to A->B and B is new activity like that B->C->D->E I have activities and finally the result should be displayed from E->Fragment which is the part of navigation Drawer A

Comment: So, that fragment is your 5th fragment of your navigation drawer?

Comment: yes I want to show that fragment directly from activity E

Comment: If you want to do this then you should call finish method in every activity when you go from one activity to another.Same way when you go from E to fragment then to should go simply as E to A activity and also pass the name of the fragment and call that method on onCreate() in A activity  by which you are calling the fragment with the fragment name as a parameter of that method.

Comment: Yes its near to my problem. I am finishing activities no issue, say me how can i access fragment directly from E, in my activity A I have initialized all fragments of navigation

Comment: You should create a method with a parameter in onCreate() of A Activity .In this parameter you should pass the frgment name .and In method you should use switch case to check the fragment name so which fragment you want to show that parameter you need to pass.

Comment: this is what exactly I need to do but I am not clear how can I implement it properly

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.a_activity);        displayView("fragment name");

Comment: Fragment fragment = null;
            fragment = new MyBooksFrag();
            if (fragment != null) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
                ft.commit();
            }

Comment: I have done this inside a method and calling it oncreate, but how can I identify that it is coming from E only? I gave if condition and checked with getIntent method but its nullpointerexception

Comment: if(getIntent().getStringExtra("action").equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
            displaySelectedScreen(R.id.latestrelease);
        }else {
            displaySelectedScreen(R.id.homeMenu);
        }... doing like this but its not working

Comment: Hey thank u so much, I solved this issue. really thanx a lot for ur help

Comment: Can anyone say how to perform it, I have a fragment in the activity, and in that fragment I have a button , onclick of that button starting new fragment, now if I click back press activity is closing other than coming back to old fragment